# Ubuntu 20.10 – move LUKS header to external device

Tags: encryption, luks, 20.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.10 to test the ZFS file system together with encryption. I discovered the system not only use the native ZFS encryption, but also encrypts the ZFS keys with LUKS (please correct me if I’m wrong).

What I’m trying to achieve is to decrypt the LUKS container with a key file and password at boot. If both are not present, it should not be possible to decrypt the container. Also I would like to keep the key file on external device. While LUKS currently doesn’t provide such a functionality, I found that moving the LUKS header to an external device is the closest solution to my problem. However, after 2 days of fighting, I still can't figure out what's wrong.

I was following the steps from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501197) answer.

Steps I took after fresh Ubuntu 20.10 installation:

1. Copying the existing LUKS header into USB drive

`sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/zd0 --header-backup-file=/dev/sdb`

2. Removing existing LUKS header from /dev/zd0

`sudo cryptsetup erase /dev/zd0`

3. Adding the following entry to /etc/crypttab

`keystore-rpool /dev/zd0 none luks,header=/dev/sdb`

4. Applying changes

`sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

After all this, typing the right password for keystore-rpool at boot always fails to decrypt the volume. By typing few times the password I’m redirected to initramfs where I can mount manually the volume with commands

```
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/zd0 keystore-rpool –header=/dev/sdb
sudo mount /dev/mapper/keystore-rpool <somemountpoint>
```

I assume something may be wrong with the entry in /etc/crypttab, but I don’t know how to check it. Also I was grepping the whole system to find out the place, where system is opening the LUKS volume and mapping to /dev/mapper/keystore-rpool, to see exactly how the command looks, but couldn’t find anything. Where is it happening? Any hints how to solve this problem would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to move the LUKS header to an external drive, but this is a workaround rather than a solution.

The file `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/zfs` was modified by changing this line

```
echo "keystore-${pool} ${ks} none luks,discard" >> "${TABFILE}"
```

to this

```
if [ $pool == "rpool" ]; then
    echo "keystore-${pool} ${ks} none luks,header=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Kingston_DataTraveler_3.0_08606E6D3FEFF351776C4F42-0:0" >> "${TABFILE}"
else
    echo "keystore-${pool} ${ks} none luks,discard" >> "${TABFILE}"
fi
```

Then updating the initrd image with command

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```